# php: Insert string before last slash in url

Tags: php, regex, replace

How do I add a string after the last slash in url?

```
current url: https://example.org/gallery/images/my-image.jpg
```

I need to add the "thumbs/" character to the last slash

The function or php code must change the address as follows

```
https://example.org/gallery/images/thumbs/my-image.jpg
```

please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways.  Try using URL and path functions and replacing:

```
$string = str_replace($dir=dirname(parse_url($string, PHP_URL_PATH)),
                      "$dir/thumbs",
                      $string);
```

Or string functions:

```
$string = str_replace($s=strrchr($string, '/'), "/thumbs$s", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the strings.

```
<?php
     $addString = "thumbs/";
     $newURL = "https://example.org/gallery/images/" . $addString . "my-image.jpg";

     echo $newURL;
```

Comment: Thankful. But the URLs are dynamic and they come from another source so I just need to add string after last slash

Comment: What is that source? You can just change the value of `$addString` to the value returned from the source.

Comment: I receive addresses from a remote server. Addresses are images. There is a thumbs folder on the same server and path. I need to add this string to the last slash to get the thumbnails!.